# Fastest way to find common items across multiple lists in C#

Tags: c#

Given the following:

```
List<List<Option>> optionLists;
```

what would be a quick way to determine the subset of Option objects that appear in all N lists? Equality is determined through some string property such as option1.Value == option2.Value.

So we should end up with `List<Option>` where each item appears only once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, this will find the list of Option objects that have a Value appearing in *every* list.

```
var x = from list in optionLists
        from option in list
        where optionLists.All(l => l.Any(o => o.Value == option.Value))
        orderby option.Value
        select option;
```

It doesn't do a "distinct" select so it'll return multiple Option objects, some of them with the same Value.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a much more efficent implementation:

```
static SortedDictionary<T,bool>.KeyCollection FindCommon<T> (List<List<T>> items)
{
  SortedDictionary<T, bool>
    current_common = new SortedDictionary<T, bool> (),
    common = new SortedDictionary<T, bool> ();

  foreach (List<T> list in items)
  {
    if (current_common.Count == 0)
    {
      foreach (T item in list)
      {
        common [item] = true;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      foreach (T item in list)
      {
        if (current_common.ContainsKey(item))
          common[item] = true;
        else
          common[item] = false;
      }
    }

    if (common.Count == 0)
    {
      current_common.Clear ();
      break;
    }

    SortedDictionary<T, bool>
      swap = current_common;

    current_common = common;
    common = swap;
    common.Clear ();
  }

  return current_common.Keys;
}
```

It works by creating a set of all items common to all lists processed so far and comparing each list with this set, creating a temporary set of the items common to the current list and the list of common items so far. Effectively an O(n.m) where n is the number of lists and m the number of items in the lists.

An example of using it:

```
static void Main (string [] args)
{
  Random
    random = new Random();

  List<List<int>>
    items = new List<List<int>>();

  for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i)
  {
    List<int>
      list = new List<int> ();

    items.Add (list);

    for (int j = 0 ; j < 100 ; ++j)
    {
      list.Add (random.Next (70));
    }
  }

  SortedDictionary<int, bool>.KeyCollection
    common = FindCommon (items);

  foreach (List<int> list in items)
  {
    list.Sort ();
  }

  for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i)
  {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; ++j)
    {
      System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write (String.Format ("{0,-4:D} ", items [j] [i]));
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine ("");
  }

  foreach (int item in common)
  {
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine (String.Format ("{0,-4:D} ", item));
  }
}
```

Comment: This is good, I would replace  `return current_common.Keys;` to `return new List<T>(current_common.Keys);` and it's perfect for my needs like so `public static List<T> FindCommon<T>(params List<T>[] lists)`

Comment: Nevermind it turns out this always just returns the last list, I couldn't figure out how to use this without `SortedDictionary`, just regular `Dictionary`, because I don't need the values themselves to change order.

Comment: @SSpoke You're right. It just returns the last list, not the intersection of all lists.

Answer (score 3):

Building on [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41159/fastest-way-to-find-common-items-across-multiple-lists-in-c#41175), since we are only interested in options that all lists have in common, we can simply check for any options in the first list that the others share:

```
var sharedOptions =
    from option in optionLists.First( ).Distinct( )
    where optionLists.Skip( 1 ).All( l => l.Contains( option ) )
    select option;
```

If an option list cannot contain duplicate entires, the `Distinct` call is unnecessary. If the lists vary greatly in size, it would be better to iterate over the options in the shortest list, rather than whatever list happens to be `First`. Sorted or hashed collections could be used to improve the lookup time of the `Contains` call, though it should not make much difference for a moderate number of items.

Answer (score 3):

Fastest to write :)

```
var subset = optionLists.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Intersect(y))
```

Answer (score 1):

what about using a *[hashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)*? that way you can do what you want in O(n) where n is the number of items in all the lists combined, and I think that's the fastest way to do it.

you just have to iterate over every list and insert the values you find into the hashset
When you insert a key that already exists you will receive *false* as the return value of the [.add method,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005.aspx) otherwise *true* is returned

Answer (score 0):

Sort, then do something akin to a merge-sort.

Basically you would do this:

1. Retrieve the first item from each list
2. Compare the items, if equal, output
3. If any of the items are before the others, sort-wise, retrieve a new item from the corresponding list to replace it, otherwise, retrieve new items to replace them all, from all the list
4. As long as you still got items, go back to 2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the performance stats, but if you don't want to roll your own method, various collections libraries have a 'Set' or 'Set(T)' object that offer the usual set procedures. (listed in the order I would use them).

1. [IESI Collections](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/GenericISet.aspx) (literally just Set classes)
2. [PowerCollections](http://www.codeplex.com/PowerCollections) (not updated in a while)
3. [C5](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) (never personally used)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by counting occurrences of all items in all lists - those items whose occurrence count is equal to the number of lists, are common to all lists:

```
    static List<T> FindCommon<T>(IEnumerable<List<T>> lists)
    {
        Dictionary<T, int> map = new Dictionary<T, int>();
        int listCount = 0; // number of lists

        foreach (IEnumerable<T> list in lists)
        {
            listCount++;
            foreach (T item in list)
            {
                // Item encountered, increment count
                int currCount;
                if (!map.TryGetValue(item, out currCount))
                    currCount = 0;

                currCount++;
                map[item] = currCount;
            }
        }

        List<T> result= new List<T>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<T,int> kvp in map)
        {
            // Items whose occurrence count is equal to the number of lists are common to all the lists
            if (kvp.Value == listCount)
                result.Add(kvp.Key);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This one fails.. I had 3 different lists with only 1 value in common and it said I have 3.. values in common since 2 lists shared 2 values that were in common yet 1 list only shared 1 value in common you cannot just tally up all the values then check against how much lists there are it doesn't work.. but I do like the code

Comment: @logicnp I was just directed to this post and I checked the method. It does not work correctly (it returns items that are not part of all the IEnumerable-s contained in lists. I took the liberty to correct it and I shall post it here:

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>
    /// The method FindCommonItems, returns a list of all the COMMON ITEMS in the lists contained in the listOfLists.
    /// The method expects lists containing NO DUPLICATE ITEMS.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="allSets"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<T> FindCommonItems<T>(IEnumerable<List<T>> allSets)
    {
        Dictionary<T, int> map = new Dictionary<T, int>();
        int listCount = 0; // Number of lists.
        foreach (IEnumerable<T> currentSet in allSets)
        {
            int itemsCount = currentSet.ToList().Count;
            HashSet<T> uniqueItems = new HashSet<T>();
            bool duplicateItemEncountered = false;
            listCount++;
            foreach (T item in currentSet)
            {
                if (!uniqueItems.Add(item))
                {
                    duplicateItemEncountered = true;
                }                        
                if (map.ContainsKey(item))
                {
                    map[item]++;
                } 
                else
                {
                    map.Add(item, 1);
                }
            }
            if (duplicateItemEncountered)
            {
                uniqueItems.Clear();
                List<T> duplicateItems = new List<T>();
                StringBuilder currentSetItems = new StringBuilder();
                List<T> currentSetAsList = new List<T>(currentSet);
                for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++)
                {
                    T currentItem = currentSetAsList[i];
                    if (!uniqueItems.Add(currentItem))
                    {
                        duplicateItems.Add(currentItem);
                    }
                    currentSetItems.Append(currentItem);
                    if (i < itemsCount - 1)
                    {
                        currentSetItems.Append(", ");
                    }
                }
                StringBuilder duplicateItemsNamesEnumeration = new StringBuilder();
                int j = 0;
                foreach (T item in duplicateItems)
                {
                    duplicateItemsNamesEnumeration.Append(item.ToString());
                    if (j < uniqueItems.Count - 1)
                    {
                        duplicateItemsNamesEnumeration.Append(", ");
                    }
                }
                throw new Exception("The list " + currentSetItems.ToString() + " contains the following duplicate items: " + duplicateItemsNamesEnumeration.ToString());
            }
        }
        List<T> result= new List<T>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<T, int> itemAndItsCount in map)
        {
            if (itemAndItsCount.Value == listCount) // Items whose occurrence count is equal to the number of lists are common to all the lists.
            {
                result.Add(itemAndItsCount.Key);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Skizz The method is not correct. It returns also items that are not common to all the lists in items.
Here is the corrected method:

```
/// <summary>.
    /// The method FindAllCommonItemsInAllTheLists, returns a HashSet that contains all the common items in the lists contained in the listOfLists,
    /// regardless of the order of the items in the various lists.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="listOfLists"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static HashSet<T> FindAllCommonItemsInAllTheLists<T>(List<List<T>> listOfLists)
    {
        if (listOfLists == null || listOfLists.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        HashSet<T> currentCommon = new HashSet<T>();
        HashSet<T> common = new HashSet<T>();

        foreach (List<T> currentList in listOfLists)
        {
            if (currentCommon.Count == 0)
            {
                foreach (T item in currentList)
                {
                    common.Add(item);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (T item in currentList)
                {
                    if (currentCommon.Contains(item))
                    {
                        common.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (common.Count == 0)
            {
                currentCommon.Clear();
                break;
            }
            currentCommon.Clear(); // Empty currentCommon for a new iteration.
            foreach (T item in common) /* Copy all the items contained in common to currentCommon. 
                                        *            currentCommon = common; 
                                        * does not work because thus currentCommon and common would point at the same object and 
                                        * the next statement: 
                                        *            common.Clear();
                                        * will also clear currentCommon.
                                        */
            {
                if (!currentCommon.Contains(item))
                {
                    currentCommon.Add(item);
                }
            }
            common.Clear();
        }

        return currentCommon;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching the 'net and not really coming up with something I liked (or that worked), I slept on it and came up with this. My `SearchResult` is similar to your `Option`. It has an `EmployeeId` in it and that's the thing I need to be common across lists. I return all records that have an `EmployeeId` in every list. It's not fancy, but it's simple and easy to understand, just what I like. For small lists (my case) it should perform just fine—and anyone can understand it!

```
private List<SearchResult> GetFinalSearchResults(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<SearchResult>> lists)
{
    Dictionary<int, SearchResult> oldList = new Dictionary<int, SearchResult>();
    Dictionary<int, SearchResult> newList = new Dictionary<int, SearchResult>();

    oldList = lists.First().ToDictionary(x => x.EmployeeId, x => x);

    foreach (List<SearchResult> list in lists.Skip(1))
    {
        foreach (SearchResult emp in list)
        {
            if (oldList.Keys.Contains(emp.EmployeeId))
            {
                newList.Add(emp.EmployeeId, emp);
            }
        }

        oldList = new Dictionary<int, SearchResult>(newList);
        newList.Clear();
    }

    return oldList.Values.ToList();
}
```