# find common items across multiple lists in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have two generic list :

```
List<string> TestList1 = new List<string>();
List<string> TestList2 = new List<string>();
TestList1.Add("1");
TestList1.Add("2");
TestList1.Add("3");
TestList2.Add("3");
TestList2.Add("4");
TestList2.Add("5");
```

What is the fastest way to find common items across these lists?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to find common items across multiple lists in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41159/fastest-way-to-find-common-items-across-multiple-lists-in-c)

Comment: @Erno I saw that thread but I couldn't use the codes.

Comment: actually that is a good question, is it compiler errors or are you having trouble adapting it to your code?  Could be important as you haven't specified what .NET version you are using, we all seem to assume you are using the latest.

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth I am using .NET 4.
@Erno That question was about List<List<Option>> optionLists;
 My question is about List<string> In that question no one used Intersect method.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Assuming you use a version of .Net that has LINQ, you can use the Intersect extension method:

```
var CommonList = TestList1.Intersect(TestList2)
```

Comment: The question is for multiple lists. Though one would just keep comparing a new list to the result of the previous intersects to achieve same effect.

Answer (score 38):

If you have lists of objects and want to get the common objects for some property then use;

```
var commons = TestList1.Select(s1 => s1.SomeProperty).ToList().Intersect(TestList2.Select(s2 => s2.SomeProperty).ToList()).ToList();
```

**Note:** *SomeProperty* refers to some criteria you want to implement.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by counting occurrences of all items in all lists - those items whose occurrence count is equal to the number of lists, are common to all lists:

```
    static List<T> FindCommon<T>(IEnumerable<List<T>> lists)
    {
        Dictionary<T, int> map = new Dictionary<T, int>();
        int listCount = 0; // number of lists

        foreach (IEnumerable<T> list in lists)
        {
            listCount++;
            foreach (T item in list)
            {
                // Item encountered, increment count
                int currCount;
                if (!map.TryGetValue(item, out currCount))
                    currCount = 0;

                currCount++;
                map[item] = currCount;
            }
        }

        List<T> result= new List<T>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<T,int> kvp in map)
        {
            // Items whose occurrence count is equal to the number of lists are common to all the lists
            if (kvp.Value == listCount)
                result.Add(kvp.Key);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Does this function the same way as `var Common = List1.Intersect(List2).Intersect(List3);` or the Intersect could break by not checking all lists at once against each other, like will it skip any of them? I used before I knew Intersect `var Common = Common.RemoveAll(i => !List1.Contains(i)); Common.RemoveAll(i => !List2.Contains(i));  = Common.RemoveAll(i => !List3.Contains(i));` Common was first populated by a single list using AddRange(), then repeated for each list and I couldn't break it either, but I had a gut feeling it would break..

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) method:

```
IEnumerable<string> result = TestList1.Intersect(TestList2);
```

Comment: Or better yet, since C# 3.0, use `var` and let the compiler keep that stuff straight.

Answer (score 2):

Sort both arrays and start from the top of both and compare if they are equal.

---

Using a hash is even faster: Put the first array in a hash, then compare every item of the second array if it is already in the hash.

I don't know those Intersect and Union are implemented. Try to find out their running time if you care about the performance. Of course they are better suited if you need clean code.

Comment: `Intersect`,`Union` and `Distinct` use a `HashSet<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Using HashSet for fast lookup. Here is the solution:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<int> list1 = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        List<int> list2 = new List<int> {1, 2, 3 };
        List<int> list3 = new List<int> {1, 2 };

        var lists = new IEnumerable<int>[] {list1, list2, list3 };

        var commons = GetCommonItems(lists);
        Console.WriteLine("Common integers:");
        foreach (var c in commons)
            Console.WriteLine(c);

    }

    static IEnumerable<T> GetCommonItems<T>(IEnumerable<T>[] lists)
    {
        HashSet<T> hs = new HashSet<T>(lists.First());
        for (int i = 1; i < lists.Length; i++)
            hs.IntersectWith(lists[i]);
        return hs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the lead of @logicnp on counting the number of lists containing each member, once you have your list of lists, it's pretty much one line of code:

```
List<int> l1, l2, l3, cmn;
List<List<int>> all;

l1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
l2 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
l3 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
all = new List<List<int>>() { l1, l2, l3 };

cmn = all.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct()
      .Where(x => all .Select(y => (y.Contains(x) ? 1 : 0))
      .Sum() == all.Count).ToList();
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
public static List<T> FindCommon<T>(IEnumerable<List<T>> Lists)
{
  return Lists.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct()
      .Where(x => Lists.Select(y => (y.Contains(x) ? 1 : 0))
      .Sum() == Lists.Count()).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the common elements of any number of lists, an Aggregate Intersect might work:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var listOfLists = new [] { 
        new [] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 
        new [] {1, 2, 3, 4}, 
        new [] {1, 2} 
    };
    
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", listOfLists.Aggregate(
        (x, y) => x.Intersect(y)
    )));  // 1, 2
}
```