# Can I compare array items? code and explanation below

Tags: c#

beginner programmer here, I'm trying to make a doodle.
a doodle is where multiple people give dates and my program should compare dates and show which of the inputted dates are the same for all three people.

```
namespace doodle_pittem
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int teller1,teller2,teller3;
        string[] Persoon1 = new string[5];
        string[] Persoon2 = new string[5];
        string[] Persoon3 = new string[5];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TxtPersoon1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))
            {
                Persoon1[teller1] = TxtPersoon1.Text;
                TxtPersoon1.Text = "";
                teller1++;
                if (teller1==5)
                {
                    TxtPersoon2.Focus();
                    TxtPersoon1.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private void TxtPersoon2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))
            {
                Persoon2[teller2] = TxtPersoon2.Text;
                TxtPersoon2.Text = "";
                teller2++;
                if (teller2 == 5)
                {
                    TxtPersoon3.Focus();
                    TxtPersoon2.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private void TxtPersoon3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))
            {
                Persoon3[teller3] = TxtPersoon3.Text;
                TxtPersoon3.Text = "";
                teller3++;
                if (teller3 == 5)
                {
                    TxtPersoon3.Enabled = false;
                    BerekenDatum();
                }
            }
        }
        private void BerekenDatum() 
        {
            string[] finaldatum = new string[15];
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                foreach (string datum1 in Persoon1)
                {
                    foreach (string datum2 in Persoon2)
                    {
                        foreach (string datum3 in Persoon3)
                        {
                            if (datum1 == datum2)
                            {
                                if (datum2 == datum3)
                                {
                                    finaldatum[i] = datum1;

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
      }
 }
```

sorry for the sloppy code or odd variable names but they're Dutch as that is my main language.
any help or tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: i'm new to overflow so i apreciate any and all help

Comment: `help or tip`...about what specifically? Where are you stuck exactly? Explain where the problem is, please, and what your current code is doing / not doing, compared to your requirements.

Comment: So what's the problem here? Your question state "can i compare array values", but you already doing this? What errors/problems are you facing? What is your expected result(s)? Also try to post the code in English, this will allow non-dutch people to get a better grasp on what the code is supposed to do

Comment: ok so my code is taking 3 array's of 5 items each(string) and saving them, the next step is to compare the array's and see if for examples item 1 from persoon1 matches item 3 from persoon2, and then it should add the matching strings to the array "finaldatum" and show them in a picturebox

Comment: gotcha english code from now on

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520006/find-common-items-across-multiple-lists-in-c-sharp) should help you figure it out