# Linq List Any can't handle Value command of generic List<List<T>>

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics, any

I get this error

```
'T' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Trying to run this code

```
public static List<T> FindCommon<T>(List<List<T>> lists)
{
    var x = from list in lists
            from option in list
            where lists.All(l => l.Any(o => o.Value == option.Value))
            orderby option.Value
            select option;
    return null;
}
```

test code

```
List<List<uint>> Patterns = new List<List<uint>>();
Patterns.Add(new List<uint>() { 1, 2, 3 });
Patterns.Add(new List<uint>() { 2, 3, 4 });
Patterns.Add(new List<uint>() { 2, 3, 4 });
Patterns.Add(new List<uint>() { 1, 2, 3 });
Patterns.Add(new List<uint>() { 5, 5, 5 });

List<uint> finalOffsets = FindCommon(Patterns);
```

should return either
1,2,3
or
2,3,4

probably 1,2,3

**Note:** the `return null;` is because I don't know what x will return I need it to be  a list.

Comment: remove the `.Value`. You're comparing `T` with `T`.  You have no constraints, I don't know what you expected `Value` to be

Comment: Yes removing `.Value` gives ` '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'`

Comment: `Value` is not a member of T. If you know something about the type you should use `public static List<T> FindCommon<T>(List<List<T>> lists) where T : Foo`

Comment: @Stefan ohhhhh thank you, now I see, is it possible to do `where T : T`? how I support all kinds of numeric datatypes

Comment: Try to use `Equals` instead of `==`

Comment: By the way, what are you trying to do? Why are you using `lists` in the where expression?

Comment: `.Equals()` yields no results at all.  I'm trying to find the most common items among all the other lists in the master list while keeping their order as well (not modifying the inner-lists).

Comment: `where T : T` doesn't say anything about the type. `where T : struct` or `where T : IFooInterface` would work. If you know its going to be an `value` type, you can use the `struct` variant.

Comment: What do you mean by "while keeping their order"?

Comment: I wanted to use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41159/fastest-way-to-find-common-items-across-multiple-lists-in-c-sharp the easier answer to understand was `static SortedDictionary<T,bool>.KeyCollection FindCommon<T> (List<List<T>> items)`  but it didn't work how I expected it to, it sorted all the inner list elements upon returning the most common answer to me which is not what I want.. I don't want the lists to be sorted at all they need to keep their order. `where lists.All(l => l.Any(o => o.Value == option.Value))` was the best answer there

Comment: The `where  lists.All(l => l.Any(o => o.Value == option.Value))` is a bit odd. Because option is a member of lists, so is o. So all members of the lists must have at least one element where the cursor equals that value.

Comment: @Stefan oh ... I get it, it was using classes instead of numbers so I don't even need this .Any() code at all, I think I need to use `FindAll` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your code compile, remove `.Value` and use the `Equals` method instead of `==`. However, this still would not give you what you want (as far as I understand your goal).

Based on my understanding of what you are trying to do, you want to find the list that is most repeated in the master list. Here is how you can do it:

First, define a comparer that knows how to compare lists:

```
public class ListEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<List<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<T> x, List<T> y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<T> obj)
    {
        //This works. But you might want to have a
        //better way for calculating the hash code
        return obj.Sum(x => x.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
public static List<T> FindCommon<T>(List<List<T>> lists)
{
    return lists.GroupBy(x => x, new ListEqualityComparer<T>())
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
        .Select(g => g.Key)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: This returns 0 Count list back

Comment: Because your lists have nothing in common. The last list contains all 5s and the first 4 lists have no 5s.

Comment: Oh I wanted to find amongst all the lists which list is the most common amongst all the other lists the dominant list(s), the example I listed has 2 dominant lists and I guess it should pick the first one I don't know.

Comment: So you want to find the list that is repeated the most times in the master list? If you have a list containing {1,2,3} and another list containing {3,2,1}, are these considered equal?

Comment: nope those are not equal, but ya the list thats repeated the most times intact. I think the code I posted should do this properly only it handles objects not numbers.

Comment: yeah that does the trick, would hashcode give same hashcode for 1,2,3 and 3,2,1?

Comment: @SSpoke, yes it would. But when two objects give the same hash code, `Equals` will be invoked to determine equality. So, a better hash code calculation would give you better performance. But correctness is already guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I tackled the problem myself.

```
public static List<T> FindCommon<T>(List<List<T>> lists)
{
    List<uint> Counts = new List<uint>();
    List<List<T>> Matches = new List<List<T>>();
    bool Found = false;

    foreach (List<T> list in lists)
    {
        Found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < Counts.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Matches[i].Count == list.Count)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
                {
                    //they not equals
                    if ((dynamic)Matches[i][j] != (dynamic)list[j])
                        goto next_loop;
                    //fully equal, increase count for repeated match found.
                    if (j == list.Count - 1)
                    {
                        Counts[i]++;
                        Found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            next_loop:
            if (Found) break;
            continue;
        }

        if (!Found)
        {
            Counts.Add(1);
            Matches.Add(list);
        }
    }

    return Matches[Counts.IndexOf(Counts.Max())];
}
```